# C++ calling functions from an array of functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Sorry I'm totally new to C++ just started this semester.  I have a question though. I know javascript some what well and I love how loose it is as a programming language. (It's both a good and a bad thing.) But there is one thing you can do in javascript that I'm not sure if you can do in c++.

I want to call some functions from an array of functions here is  a link of that done in javascript. [Javascript Array of Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908378/javascript-array-of-functions#4908388).  My idea is to write a for loop that will go through functions in the order I want. (from first to last.)  If there is an alternative to this I will be fine with that.  I could even name the functions with a number after them like function1 for example if that might help.  I'm not sure if this is possible, but any help or anything would be awesome thanks.

Comment: Yes! This is possible with the [function pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer)

Comment: @awesomeyi Sweet thanks for the quick comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you talk about "function pointer"?

```
void f1() { .. }
void f2() { .. }
void f3() { .. }

typedef void (*pf)();

pf arf[3] = { f1, f2, f3 };

arf[0]();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the function pointer

```
struct parent
{
   virtual void f();
}

struct child1 : parent
{
  void f(){};
}

struct child2 : parent
{
  void f(){};
}

struct child3 : parent
{
  void f(){};
}

.
.
.

struct childn : parent
{
  void f(){};
}


parent array = {child1,child2,child3,.....,childn};

array[n].f();

each child classes will contain different implementations of f(), so you can 

create an array of child structs and invoke the methods through the for loop.
```