# Javascript function array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I am wondering how to make an array with functions and then randomizing one and call it. Here is an example of what I have tested.

```js
functions = [f1(), f2(), f3(), f4()];
rand = functions[Math.floor(Math.random() * functions.length)];

$('p').click(function() {
  rand[0]();
}
```

I have searched and tried multiple supposed solutions but none of them worked(including this one: [Javascript Array of Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908378/javascript-array-of-functions)).

Answer (score 5):

Create the array using function references, and then use the random key generation in the click handler

```js
function log(func) {
  $('#x').html(func)
}

function f1() {
  log('f1')
}

function f2() {
  log('f2')
}

function f3() {
  log('f3')
}

function f4() {
  log('f4')
}

functions = [f1, f2, f3, f4];

$('p').click(function() {
  var rand = functions[Math.floor(Math.random() * functions.length)];
  rand();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="x"></div>
<p>Click</p>
```

Comment: May I ask what the point of the log function and x div is? Tried it without them and it works great. Thanks btw.

Comment: @ItsNotAbyss that was just to demonstrate that the functions are getting called... like when `f1` is called the div's text is changed to f1 etc

Answer (score 0):

1. By adding a `()` after the function names( `f1()` ), you are effectively *executing* the function. You must pass a reference of the function to the array so that you can invoke it later. So,

   ```
   functions = [f1(), f2(), f3(), f4()];
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   functions = [f1, f2, f3, f4];
   ```
2. You seem to be calculating `rand` only once, because it is not placed in the `click` event. Include this,

   ```
   rand = functions[Math.floor(Math.random() * functions.length)];
   ```

   in your event handler.
3. `rand` is not an array. It contains a reference of one function, which can be invoked by calling it, like this :

   ```
   rand();
   ```

Your full code, along with some additions has been fiddled here : http://jsfiddle.net/sq623mrc/