# Loop through javascript functions

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a series of numbered javascript functions and I would like to loop through the functions based on a variable called **total**. If total is 3, I would like to run load1(data), load2(data), load(3) data; if it is 2 just the first two functions so on.

This seems simple enough, but I can't seem to get it working right. In the simplest form the code below works.

```
i = 1;
if (i <= total){load1(data);}i++;
if (i <= total){load2(data);}i++;
if (i <= total){load3(data);}i++;
if (i <= total){load4(data);}i++;
if (i <= total){load5(data);}
```

But I can't seem to be able to put that in a loop. I have tried the following:

Trying to put the functions in an array and calling them in a for loop based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908378/javascript-array-of-functions) thread. //throws a function undefined error.

Call it inside a loop like this:

```
var f = new Function("return load"+i+"(data)")(); //throws a data not defined error
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of `loadN` functions create a `load` array, then it would be as easy as `load.slice(0, total).map(f => f(data))`

Comment: @zerkms - Could you elaborate please?

Comment: What exactly? Don't create `N` separate functions, create an array that holds them.

Comment: Ah, I see; let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `loadX` is global function, you could do like below:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
  window['load'+i](data);
}
```

Comment: Yes, they're global functions and this worked! Appreciate it.