# Generating a list of functions based on an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am just wondering if there is a way in JavaScript where I can create a new list of functions based on all "name" values in the object.

For example, with the following object:

```
var object_ = [{"name": "first_function", "child": ["1a", "1b"]},
               {"name": "second_function", "child": ["2a", "2b"]},
               {"name": "third_function", "child": ["3a", "3b"]}];
```

I would like to create the following functions:

```
function first_function(){
      console.log("1a, 1b");
};

function second_function(){
      console.log("2a, 2b");
};

function third_function(){
      console.log("3a, 3b");
};
```

Thank you

Comment: Basically your array contains reference of the functions.

Comment: What is your use case and what higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Are you trying to pass references to functions to `console.log()`?  Or are you trying to invoke the functions and pass the output of those functions to `console.log()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Array of Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908378/javascript-array-of-functions)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear previously. I have edited the description.

Comment: So now with your update...what is reason for needing multiple functions that all seem to do same thing and you want to create on the fly vs one function that takes your `child` value and works with that? still not clear what higher level objective is

Comment: Could also be that you have misused the term *"create functions"* rather than use `name` to reference an existing function

Comment: @charlietfl This is only the simplified version. The actual use case has child values with more complicated and random arrays,

Comment: Fine but still not clear if you mean to match name to existing methods or what *"automatically create"* means exactly. An existing method (found by using name) is easy to pass parameters into whereas dynamically creating the business logic inside an automatically created function is a whole different story

Comment: @charlietfl I see. I am trying to create a non-existing method.

Comment: So now you are on the difficult path. Making a new function is one thing...telling it what to do is another. You haven't touched on that nor on what higher level problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, given a list of metadata to create functions with:

```
var functionData = [
    { name: 'first_function', children: ['1a', '1b'] },
    { name: 'second_function', children: ['2a', '2b'] },
];
```

We can dynamically create a function by the name of each one's `name` property:

```
functionData.forEach(({name, children}) => {
    // create a function and put it under that name
    this[name] = () => {
        // and make sure it logs the corresponding data
        console.log(...children);
    }
})
```

Which, for example can then be called like so:

```
first_function();
// logs "1a", "1b"
```

Or even:

```
this[functionData[0].name]();
// logs "1a", "1b"
```

I added the functions to the `this` object just as an example.

This works for a non-strict-mode browser console; because an unqualified reference to a function tries to look for it on the `window`, which is the `this` context in that environment.