# NodeJS converting sequential function calls into an array of functions

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have a function making a callback to other functions in the class in linear fashion.

```
async runTask() {
    debug('runTask');
    debug(this.taskData);

    try {
      // Short circuit for testing
      if (process.env.TASKTIMER) {
        return setTimeout(() => {
          this.taskComplete();
        }, process.env.TASKTIMER);
      }

      // Setup project folder & Git Clone
      await this.pullPackageWait();

      // Create input and output directory
      await this.mkIODirWait();

      // Store task data as json
      await this.writeTaskDataJSONWait();

      // Download Inputs From Amazon
      await this.downloadInputsWait();

      // Link Input files
      await this.linkInputsWait();

      // Download Resources From Amazon
      await this.downloadResourcesWait();

      // Relax permission on tmp directory
      await this.chmodTaskDir();

      // Destroys the job after timeout
      await this.jobTimeout();

      // Determine Handler
      console.log(this.taskData.handler);
      await this.initHandler();
      await this._handler.startJob();
    } catch (err) {
      this.logger.error(err);
      return this.taskError();
    }
```

I'm trying to convert the function calls into an array of functions following the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4908388/11511781) answer. After refactoring my functions looks as follows:

```
 async runTask() {
    debug('runTask');
    debug(this.taskData);

    try {
      // Short circuit for testing
      if (process.env.TASKTIMER) {
        return setTimeout(() => {
          this.taskComplete();
        }, process.env.TASKTIMER);
      }

      let currentFunction = 0;
      const functionsToRun = [
        this.pullPackageWait,
        this.mkIODirWait,
        this.writeTaskDataJSONWait,
        this.downloadInputsWait,
        this.linkInputsWait,
        this.downloadResourcesWait,
        this.chmodTaskDir,
        this.jobTimeout,
      ];

      debug('Before The Loop');
      for (currentFunction; currentFunction < functionsToRun.length; currentFunction++) {
        debug('In The Loop');
        await functionsToRun[currentFunction]();
        console.log('Writing to the file');
        await this.writeState();
      }

      // Determine Handler
      console.log(this.taskData.handler);
      await this.initHandler();
      await this._handler.startJob();
    } catch (err) {
      this.logger.error(err);
      return this.taskError();
    }
```

With the original code the entire program runs normally, but after conversion it seems to break at the first callback. Did I make a mistake somewhere in conversion?

Comment: functionsToRun elements can be strings and called `this[currentFunction]()`, seems like wasted memory to me

Comment: You probably have issues with `this` binding. Either use Lawrence's idea and store the function names as strings or store them as `this.pullPackageWait.bind(this) ...` etc

Comment: I've had them as string before, but that seems to be messing with types, maybe it was because of `for of`. I'll give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: nitpick, replace `console.log` with `debug`, your thank me later (code review) ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Arguably storing a function pointer (4 or 8 bytes per function depending on 32 or 64 bit interpreter) uses less memory than the function names as strings (between 10-20 bytes per function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely source of error in the refactored code is incorrect `this` binding. Note that the following:

```
this.foo();
```

is not the same as:

```
let foo = this.foo;
foo();
```

When calling `this.foo()` the `this` value inside `foo()` will be the same `this` as `this.foo`. When calling `foo()` the `this` value inside `foo()` will either be `undefined` or the global object, depending on weather you have strict mode on or not.

For a complete explanation of how `this` works refer to my answer to this other question: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628)

---

## TLDR

The solution is to either store the function names as strings:

```
const functionsToRun = [
    'pullPackageWait',
    'mkIODirWait',
    'writeTaskDataJSONWait',
    'downloadInputsWait',
    'linkInputsWait',
    'downloadResourcesWait',
    'chmodTaskDir',
    'jobTimeout',
];
```

Then call each function as:

```
await this[functionsToRun[index]]();
```

Or `.bind()` the functions:

```
const functionsToRun = [
    this.pullPackageWait.bind(this),
    this.mkIODirWait.bind(this),
    this.writeTaskDataJSONWait.bind(this),
    this.downloadInputsWait.bind(this),
    this.linkInputsWait.bind(this),
    this.downloadResourcesWait.bind(this),
    this.chmodTaskDir.bind(this),
    this.jobTimeout.bind(this),
];
```

and call them the way you're currently doing:

```
await functionsToRun[currentFunction]();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The fist way worked like a charm.